# Get QSS option programmatically

Tags: qt, fonts, qtstylesheets

I have the following problem: I have a custom stylesheet containing a font option `* {font-family: "Times New Roman";}`. I apply this stylesheet to my application when it is created. After that I need to query this option in my C++ code, but I can't find a right way to do it. I try to call `QApplication::font().family()` and `QWidget().font().family()`, but both of these methods returns default values. As far as I can judge QApplication's style is applied to QWidget after it is fully created (maybe when it is shown for the first time, but I'm not sure). Can anybody help?
**UPD**
The following code illustrates my problem:
**.qss:**

```
* {
    font: bold large "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

This style sheet is used to setup QApplication. I want also to have a font from .qss to be used as default font for my QWebView:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QFile file("default.qss");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    app->setStyleSheet(file.readAll());
    // some work is done here
    // ...
    QWebView view;
    QFont font = QWidget().font();
    view->settings()->setFontFamily(QWebSettings::StandardFont, font.family());
    view->settings()->setFontSize(QWebSettings::DefaultFontSize, font.pointSize());
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What if you parse the string returned by `QApplication::styleSheet()` function?

Comment: @vahancho, yes, I thought about it, but as far as I know there is no any standard QSS parser, and parsing a raw QString seems too tedious

Comment: Please post a complete example that reproduces the problem. IIRC the styles are not parsed until the event loop has been entered and the widgets are visible. Perhaps you're getting the application font way before Qt parses the stylesheet.